# Some issue while displaying the records in table in asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net

Through query I am fetching all the required records from database but all the records are not displaying in the display table.I am not able to find out why all the records are not displaying. For eg: if I am fetching 6 records, then only 3 records are displayed.(odd records are displayed i.e;1st, 3rd and 5th records are displayed).

```
for (j = 0; j < chbStatuslist.Items.Count; j++)
        {
            if (chbStatuslist.Items[j].Selected)
            {
                carrStatus = chbStatuslist.Items[j].Value.Split('.');
                if (carrStatus.Length == 2)
                {
                    dTable = getConn.GetAdapterDatatable("SELECT cpCode, cpDate, cpNo,csShortName,pjName, cpComplaint, cpMobile, cpSev, cpCompBy, cpStatus FROM complaint,customermaster,project WHERE cpDel='R' and cpCustomer=csCode and cpProject=pjCode and (cpCustomer='" + cmbCustomer.SelectedValue + "' or 'ALL'='" + cmbCustomer.SelectedValue + "') and cpSev='" + cmbSev.SelectedItem + "' and cpDate between '" + cFDate + "' and '" + cTDate + "' and cpStatus>='" + carrStatus[0] + "' and cpStatus<='" + carrStatus[1] + "' Order by cpNo ", Global.conStrDatabase);
                }
                else if (carrStatus.Length == 1)
                {
                    dTable = getConn.GetAdapterDatatable("SELECT cpCode, cpDate, cpNo,csShortName,pjName, cpComplaint, cpMobile, cpSev, cpCompBy, cpStatus FROM complaint,customermaster,project WHERE cpDel='R' and cpCustomer=csCode and cpProject=pjCode and (cpCustomer='" + cmbCustomer.SelectedValue + "' or 'ALL'='" + cmbCustomer.SelectedValue + "') and cpSev='" + cmbSev.SelectedItem + "' and cpDate between '" + cFDate + "' and '" + cTDate + "' and cpStatus='" + carrStatus[0] + "' Order by cpNo ", Global.conStrDatabase);
                }
                for (int ni = 0; ni < dTable.Rows.Count; ni++)
                {
                    tRow = new TableRow();

                    tCell = new TableCell();
                    tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

                    tCell = new TableCell();
                    tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

                    tCell = new TableCell();
                    tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

                    tCell = new TableCell();
                    tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

                    tCell = new TableCell();
                    tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

                    tCell = new TableCell();
                    tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

                    tCell = new TableCell();
                    tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

                    tCell = new TableCell();
                    tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

                    tCell = new TableCell();
                    tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

                    tCell = new TableCell();
                    tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

                    if (dTable.Rows[ni]["cpDate"].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        tRow.Cells[0].Text = DateTime.Parse(dTable.Rows[ni]["cpDate"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    }
                    tRow.Cells[1].Text = dTable.Rows[ni]["cpNo"].ToString();
                    tRow.Cells[2].Text = dTable.Rows[ni]["cpComplaint"].ToString();
                    tRow.Cells[3].Text = dTable.Rows[ni]["cpMobile"].ToString();
                    tRow.Cells[4].Text = dTable.Rows[ni]["cpCompBy"].ToString();
                    tRow.Cells[5].Text = dTable.Rows[ni]["csShortName"].ToString();
                    tRow.Cells[6].Text = dTable.Rows[ni]["pjName"].ToString();
                    tRow.Cells[7].Text = dTable.Rows[ni]["cpSev"].ToString();
                    tRow.Cells[8].Text = dTable.Rows[ni]["cpStatus"].ToString();
                    tRow.Cells[9].Text = "<a href='../Reports/rptComplaint.aspx?CId=WD" + dTable.Rows[ni]["cpCode"].ToString() + "&RequestId=" + cRequestId + "&FromDate=" + cFDate + " > View </a>";
                    dispTable.Rows.Add(tRow);
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `chbStatuslist.Items.Count` have the expected number?

Does `dTable.Rows.Count` have the expected number?

If you set a breakpoint for each `dTable.Rows[ni]["cpNo"].ToString();` do you see the ones you expect?

Are you getting any javascript errors?

Can you look at the request going back to the browser (e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in chrome, then network tab) and see the expected data being sent?

Comment: I have set breakpoint and checked, checkboxlist count and dtable count shows correct count value and  dTable.Rows[ni]["cpNo"].ToString() is also showing correct values in each loop.

Comment: Thankyou. I got the required result. I had missed a single quote in tRow.Cells[9].Text = "<a href='../Reports/rptComplaint.aspx?CId=WD" + dTable.Rows[ni]["cpCode"].ToString() + "&RequestId=" + cRequestId + "&FromDate=" + cFDate + "' > View </a>";

Comment: @user2944673 - glad that you got it going.